# how to download excel file in python and streamlit?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, streamlit, pandas.excelwriter

I have a Python script that read files and convert it to dataframe using Python and streamlit. Then I want to create a function to allows the user to download this dataframe as an Excel file with extension `.xls`.

So I tried to read the dataframe and convert it to an Excel file using these two functions:

```
pd.ExcelWriter
df.to_excel
```

But when I try to download the file using a link the file doesn't download and displays this error:

```
Failed-Network error
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import streamlit as st

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('update2.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, index = False, header=True,encoding='utf-8')
with open(writer,'rb') as f:
    b64 = base64.b64encode(f.read())
    href = f'<a href="data:file/xls;base64,{b64}" download="new_file.{extension}">Download {extension}</a>'

st.write(href, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the streamlit latest release(above 1.0.0):

Use

```
st.download_button
```

Displays a download button widget.

This is useful when you would like to provide a way for your users to download a file directly from your app.

*Note that the data to be downloaded is stored in memory while the user is connected, so it's a good idea to keep file sizes under a couple of hundred megabytes to conserve memory.*

Here is a sample code from the [discussion](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/download-button-for-csv-or-xlsx-file/17385), that can be helpful to download excel files...

```
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
from pyxlsb import open_workbook as open_xlsb
import streamlit as st

def to_excel(df):
    output = BytesIO()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00'}) 
    worksheet.set_column('A:A', None, format1)  
    writer.save()
    processed_data = output.getvalue()
    return processed_data
df_xlsx = to_excel(df)
st.download_button(label=' Download Current Result',
                                data=df_xlsx ,
                                file_name= 'df_test.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
import streamlit as st

def to_excel(df: pd.DataFrame):
    in_memory_fp = BytesIO()
    df.to_excel(in_memory_fp)
    # Write the file out to disk to demonstrate that it worked.
    in_memory_fp.seek(0, 0)
    return in_memory_fp.read()

cols = ["col1", "col2"]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{k: 0.0 for k in cols} for _ in range(25)])
excel_data = to_excel(df)
file_name = "excel.xlsx"
st.download_button(
    f"Click to download {file_name}",
    excel_data,
    file_name,
    f"text/{file_name}",
    key=file_name
)
```

Answer (score -2):

line 5 can't be executed since you havent assigned any excel to the DataFrame df.

try something like this in your code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('update2.xlsx')
```

I hope, this helped.

Take care

Comment: first read_csv is for csv not for excel file as i think.
second i need to write to teh excel and not read from it .
third at the third line i am opening the excel file in order to read

Answer (score -3):

```
def get_binary_file_downloader_html(bin_file, file_label='File'):
     with open(bin_file, 'rb') as f:
         data = f.read()
     bin_str = base64.b64encode(data).decode()
     href = f'<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,{bin_str}" download="{os.path.basename(bin_file)}">Descargar {file_label}</a>'
     return href

st.markdown(get_binary_file_downloader_html('Wip_QRY.xlsx', 'Excel'), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```