# download python-pptx from streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit, python-pptx

I'm using [python-pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [streamlit](https://streamlit.io/). I'm creating a ppt from python like this:

```
from pptx import Presentation
import streamlit as st

prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

title.text = "Hello, World!"
subtitle.text = "python-pptx was here!"

#prs.save('test.pptx') # This works, just saves it in the app path.
# But I want a clickable button, to be downloaded from the streamlit app.
# Therefore, I've tried to do this: 

st.download_button(label = 'Download ppw', data = prs, file_name = 'my_power.ppt')
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Invalid binary data format: <class 'NoneType'>
```

**Requeriments to reproduce:**

Install streamlit (`pip install streamlit`)

Install python-pptx (`pip install python-pptx`)

Comment: oh really sorry! I was in vacations :P. Awesome!! many thanks @StefanoFiorucci-anakin87

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70120061/10883094) and I understood that **you have to generate a binary representation** for your `Presentation` object.

```
from pptx import Presentation
import streamlit as st
from io import BytesIO

prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

title.text = "Hello, World!"
subtitle.text = "python-pptx was here!"

# save the output into binary form
binary_output = BytesIO()
prs.save(binary_output) 

st.download_button(label = 'Download ppw',
                   data = binary_output.getvalue(),
                   file_name = 'my_power.pptx')
```